# What is the simplest amount of code that would prevent a node process from exiting?

Tags: node.js, unix, process

I'm looking for a way to log text in a javascript node.js file in the terminal and not have that process exit.

```
console.log('hello-world')
process.doNotExit()
```

There are many different things I've done in the past like connect to a database that prevent the process from exiting.

I'm looking for something different from the `forever` module.

Comment: Why is it important that you artificially keep the process alive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` and do nothing:

```
var i= setInterval(function(){}, 2147483647);
```

The value comes from [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_arg), it's approximately 25 days.
Use `clearInterval` or `unref` when you are ready to exit (see [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/timers.html) for further details).

Naïve, but pretty easy. Isn't it?